# How do I locate files which were modified within the last 10 days but and NOT in a "CVS", "build" or "classes" folder on a bash terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, cvs

Trying to locate a very specific set of recently changed files within a code repository on a Linux box using a remote terminal session. There are some specific folders names which contain files that are build/SCM cruft that I do not want polluting the real matches I need. No fancy SCM software is available to give me a change list, remember this is just a PuTTY window I have. I am hoping to craft a command that will work on a very spartan linux distribution with few optional packages included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
find '(' -name CVS -or -name build -or -name classes -prune ')' -or -mtime +10
```

The `'(' -name CVS -or -name build -or -name classes -prune ')'` part skips the directories you want to skip

And `-mtime +10` matches files that was modified 10 days ago.